# Receiving error as 'org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window' when tried to find element in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to launch IE webdriver and find any element for the link provided.
The same problem runs well in Chrome and FF but throwing below mentioned error.
I googled and updated the Registry file as well with required value but still getting error.
**Updated Registry details:**
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE

**Error received:**
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30 milliseconds
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'IBM298-PC0BYATM', ip: '192.168.0.6', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{se:ieOptions={browserAttachTimeout=0.0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000.0, ie.useLegacyFileUploadDialogHandling=false, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0.0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:36802/, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 7fd5e21f-9930-4a06-9ec4-cd379a1930f3
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=lst-ib}

## Code Snippet:

```
@Test
    public void GoogleSearch() throws Exception
    {
    UtilityLibrary.Instance.get("http://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    UtilityLibrary.Instance.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("TestNG Test");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
```

## Utility Code Snippet:

```
public class UtilityLibrary {

    public static WebDriver Instance = null;
    public static String Browser = "IE";

    public static void WebdriverInstance()
    {
        if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome"))
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            Instance= new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if (Browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE"))
        {
            //DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            //caps.setCapability(
              //  InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,
               // true);
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\Drivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");            
            Instance= new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        Instance.manage().window().maximize();
        Instance.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

Please suggest if further more configuration needs to be changed.

Comment: without seeing the code in your `UtilityLibrary`, this question is not possible to answer

Comment: Hi Corey,

Please find the code snippet of UtilityLibrary class: